# The number of ideals in a number ring below a given norm

Tags: reference-request, analytic-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I'm doing some number theory, and my deficient knowledge of algebraic number theory shows itself; I have to ask for help.

Suppose $K$ is a number field, and we want to count the ideals in $\mathcal O_K$.

It is Knopfmacher, who, in his book about abstract analytic number theory, states that
$$
N_K(x) = A_K x + O(x^δ),
$$
where $N_K(x)$ is the number of ideals of norm less than or equal to $x \in \mathbb R$, $A_K$ is some "constant depending on $K$" (in fact a function of $K$), and $δ = 1 - 2/(1 + [K : \mathbb Q])$.

My questions are:

1. What is $A_K$?
2. Where may I find a (readable; I'm a novice at this subject and don't know all the "standard" steps) proof of this theorem, purportedly going back to Kronecker and Weber?
3. When considering several number fields, is the error term uniform or does it depend on the number field? If so, how?

Comment: For 1 and 2, see chapter 6 in Marcus's Number Fields.

Comment: @Wojowu: Marcus' book gives a worse error term.

Comment: Are you sure you got your $\delta$ right? As written it is very negative. At any rate, the constant $A_K$ is the same regardless of the error term.

Comment: I'm sure I didn't get it right. Now it's fixed. @Wojowu (But I did write "this theorem", refering to the right δ.)

Comment: A proof with this exponent is given in Landau's book, "Einführung in die Elementare und analytische Theorie der algebraischen Zahlen und der Ideale" (Chapter 5). $A_K$ is the residue of the Dedekind zeta function at $s=1$.

Answer (score 7):

[Lowry-Duda, Tanagichi, and Thorne](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00209-021-02862-z) proved that if $K$ is a number field with

- absolute discriminant $D_K$,
- $d=[K:\mathbb{Q}] = r_1+2r_2$, where $r_1$ (resp. $r_2$) is the number of real (resp. complex) embeddings into $\mathbb{C}$,
- $h$ the order of the ideal class group of $K$,
- regulator $R$,
- $w$ roots of unity,

then there exists an effectively computable constant $c(d)>0$, depending only on $d$, such that if $X\geq 3$, then

$$\Big|N_K(X) - \frac{2^{r_1}(2\pi)^{r_2}hR}{w D_K^{1/2}}X\Big| \leq c(d) D_K^{\frac{1}{d+1}}X^{1-\frac{2}{d+1}}(\log X)^{d-1}.$$

This follows from a uniform version of Landau's theorem that holds in considerably greater generality.